# Upper bound on the geodesic distance in a Lipschitz domain

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I was wondering if the following result is true. If yes, could you please suggest a reference. The result seems to have been used at several papers without quoting any reference. Is the proof straightforward enough not be substantiated with a reference?

**Result:**

Let $n\geqslant 2$ and let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded, connected and Lipschitz. There exists a constant $C=C(\Omega)>0$ with the property that, for all $x,y\in\Omega$, there is a Lipschitz path $\gamma_{x,y}:[0,1]\to\Omega$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{x,y}(0)=x, \gamma_{x,y}(1)=y\text{ and }\int_{0}^{1}\|\gamma_{x,y}'(t)\|dt\leqslant C\|x-y\|. \ \ \          (1)
\end{equation}

**Further question:**
In the aforementioned result, since $x,y$ are in the interior, is it reasonable to expect a **smooth** path $\gamma_{x,y}$ satisfying (1)?

Comment: Yes it is straightforward: since $\Omega$ is Lipschits the condition holds if $|x-y|<\varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon>0$; since $\Omega$ is bounded it can be covered by a finite number of $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods. Whence the statement follows.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin : Can you detail "the condition holds if |x−y|<ε for some fixed ε>0"?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Thanks for your comment. Could you please elaborate on the first part.